# How to run Startup.ConfigureService first and then run HostingStartup's

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I've couple of HostingStartup implementations(plugin's) like below.

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(ClassLibrary1.MyCustomStartup1))]
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(ClassLibrary2.MyCustomStartup2))]
```

And added environment variable like below:

```
ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES=ClassLibrary1;ClassLibrary2
```

Below is *Startup.cs* of my API project

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      // I've DI registration here and i want to call this first and then Any HostStartup's
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }
}
```

So, When i run the project, The order of execution is MyCustomStartup1, MyCustomStartup2 and then Startup.ConfigureServices.

However, I want to change the order of default execution. First run `Startup.ConfigureServices` and then MyCustomStartup1 and then MyCustomStartup2.

Comment: Please refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-provided-by-the-hosting-startup): *Provide configuration to the app using UseConfiguration to load the configuration before the app's ConfigureAppConfiguration delegates execute. The app's configuration values take priority over those provided by the hosting startup using this approach.* Then, to order the hosting startup assembly, you could use the UseSetting() method to configure it.

Comment: @zhilv I followed same, it is to order the host start-up but not start-up